# Application logging with multiple docker replicas (containers)

Tags: docker, logging, .net-core

We have a .NET core app, which logs its output to files, for eg. `portal-20200430-000.log`. In DEV environment, all is well :)

App is deployed via docker service, which initializes 3 replicas - 3 docker containers. We want to have all the logs from all the containers (replicas) in one place, so we mapped the file systems between the host machine and the containers via [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#add-bind-mounts-volumes-or-memory-filesystems).

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    image: portal:0.0.1
    --- snipped content ---
    volumes:
      - "/home/portal/Dev/Logs:/app/Logs"
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
```

Each container (replica) is outputting its own logs to `/app/Logs/portal-20200430-000.log` inside container, but this folder is mapped to `/home/portal/Dev/Logs` on the host. So all 3 containers are writing into the same file on the host, which is not ok - some of the logs get lost, these 3 containers are overwritting each others logs, etc.

I suppose possible solutions are:

- change the file name of each container's log (but logging is done via external [Karambolo logger](https://github.com/adams85/filelogger), that has filenames hardcoded inside appsettings.json. These settings are common to all container replicas)
- instruct each docker replica to map a different volume - is that even possible?

Is there another solution?

Comment: Why not make your life easy by using ELK (ElasticSearch LogStash, Kibana) stack for logging? Another solution instead of writing directly to files, you can logs to queue for all containers and you will need custom service that will read the queue and write the data into one file.

Comment: @CodeNotFound: ELK looks good, but I think its a little bit of an overkill for our little app. The same goes for the queue, given that each container is logging just fine on their own, but when there are more replicas, things get ugly. I just need a way to customize settings for each replica.

Answer (score 0):

Note - This is a **partial** solution.

When you start `docker-compose` with replicas, the only difference inside the container is environment variable `hostname` (unless set by `docker-compose.yml` to a static value).

Create docker-compose.yml as below:-

```
version: '3'
services:

  test_logging:
    image: bash
    entrypoint: bash
    command: -c "sleep 3600"
    deploy:
        replicas: 2
```

Run the containers:-

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Now, if you execute bash in interactive mode in the running container, you will see following environment variables.

```
$ docker exec -it test_test_logging_1 bash
bash-5.1# env
HOSTNAME=f000d941eab2
PWD=/
_BASH_BASELINE_PATCH=16
HOME=/root
_BASH_VERSION=5.1.16
_BASH_BASELINE=5.1.16
_BASH_LATEST_PATCH=16
TERM=xterm
SHLVL=1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
_=/usr/bin/env

$ docker exec -it test_test_logging_2 bash
bash-5.1# env
HOSTNAME=0b848ef70202
PWD=/
_BASH_BASELINE_PATCH=16
HOME=/root
_BASH_VERSION=5.1.16
_BASH_BASELINE=5.1.16
_BASH_LATEST_PATCH=16
TERM=xterm
SHLVL=1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

As you can see, only `hostname` differs between different docker containers. You can use hostname to generate different filenames for different log files.

**Disk Space Issue**

However, this wont be enough. By default [FileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.FileHandler) (logging) will use as much space as needed. Its best to move to [RotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler) or [TimedRotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler). Note that, its better to use `RotatingFileHandler` due to sudden surge of too many error logs which can happen due to any number of reasons. By the time, `TimedRotatingFileHandler` will rotate the files, you might end up using all the disk space.

Note that `RotatingFileHandler` doesnt provide compression of rotated log files, this needs to be additionally implemented.
P.S. Be aware that with R replicas, and each replica using B `backupCount` files for `RotatingFileHandler` and S `maxBytes`, you will use `R x B x S`
Bytes disk space with no compression.

Finally, this is a partial solution, since if you do a restart of the service, ***the hostname will change***, and new log files will be created. However, even with this issue, the above partial solution will work if you integrate log services like [ELK](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elk-stack) stack to collect older log files for further analysis of log files such as error monitoring.

Comment: `You can use hostname to generate different filenames for different log files.` -> Unfortunately not, see the first 'possible solution' that I posted: `change the file name of each container's log (but logging is done via external Karambolo logger, that has filenames hardcoded inside appsettings.json. These settings are common to all container replicas)`
Thanks anyway :)